# When do I have to use binding redirects?

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget

Project A uses `log4net 1.2.13.0`, and depends on Library B, which uses `log4net 1.2.11.0`. If I do `Package Manager Console> Add-BindingRedirect`, I get a correct binding redirect in `app.config`:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.13.0" newVersion="1.2.13.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I thought that this one is *required* in order for the build to complete. But build succeeds without the redirect as well. Here what I see in build log (verbosity set to detailed):

> Unified primary reference "log4net, Version=1.2.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a".
>         Using this version instead of original version "1.2.11.0" in "C:\Users\vorou\code\ConsoleApplication1\packages\LibraryB.dll" because AutoUnify is 'true'.

What is that AutoUnify all about? Which one is better, i.e. are there any advantages in having an explicit redirect in .config?

Also, as I can remember, in some cases you are *required* to add binding redirects. Otherwise the app will blow up at runtime. What are these cases and why that `AutoUnify` magic isn't working for them?

---

**UPD** Here's an excerpt from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad3f294.aspx) about `AutoUnify`:

> This parameter is used for building assemblies, such as DLLs, which cannot have a normal App.Config file.
>   When true, the resulting dependency graph is automatically treated as if there were an App.Config file passed in to the AppConfigFile parameter. This virtual App.Config file has a bindingRedirect entry for each conflicting set of assemblies such that the highest version assembly is chosen. A consequence of this is that there will never be a warning about conflicting assemblies because every conflict will have been resolved.

It looks like redirects in .config don't play any role in my case. The problem is Library B can't satisfy it's dependencies, and `AutoUnify` solves it with that “pretend there are binding redirects” rule.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Versioning is a big topic, can't do it justice in a single SO post.  So break-neck speed:

These kind of shenanigans are necessary when you use multiple Nuget packages and they have a common dependency.  Like log4net or NewtonSoft.Json, very common libraries that don't have an installer that put the assembly in the GAC.

Problem is, each Nuget package is very likely to built with a different version of these core support libraries.  And such a package is unlikely to get enough updates to keep the current with the latest release, the package author favors the version he tested his code with.  So you'll easily end up with one assembly in your build directory that asks for 1.2.11.0 and another that asks for 1.2.13.0

That cannot work.  The CLR insists on an *exact* version match when it loads an assembly.  And has to load it from your build directory and can't rely on the GAC to supply them.  There can be only one copy of the DLL, inevitably one of the package libraries is going to get the wrong version and your program will crash.  Not good, you have a problem you can't solve without a rebuild of the Nuget package.

That's what the binding redirect solves.  It only has an affect at runtime, not build time.  It tells the CLR, "if it asks for 1.2.11.0 then just load 1.2.13.0 instead.  Or more generally with this specific binding redirect: "if it asks for *any* version less than 1.2.13.0".  Problem solved, no crash anymore.  Fingers crossed that the package still works with that newer version.  They pretty commonly do when only the revision number is different.  No hard guarantee however.

Another thing that needs to be decided, this happens at build time, is which specific version of the library should be selected.  Do you want 1.2.11.0 or 1.2.13.0?  That's what AutoUnify does.  Nothing very complicated, it picks the higher version.

Comment: If we have A -> C(v2.1)  and B -> C(v2.2) why not treating A's and B's dependencies as their own business? (Because CLR etc...) but again why CLR is forcing such a constraint? Thanks!

Comment: The CLR has no such constraint.  You have two files named C.dll, there is only one place you can put them so they don't overwrite each other.  Don't use it.

Comment: I lack knowledge here but why C needs to be exposed out of A, and B. A and B should be standalone/self-contained dlls. (I'm not arguing just want to get a better understanding of the "why"). Thanks for your patience

Comment: There is absolutely no guarantee that your software will not crash using the latest version of that dependency (1.2.13.0), since Library B was tested specifically with version 1.2.11.0.  As Hans said: "Fingers crossed that the package still works with that newer version." - that means you are accepting that version conflict resolution at your own consent and risk. +1